# SQL challenge - Identifying UK post codes in a 30 mile radius

Tags: sql

I have two SQL tables:

`[UK Post Code]` with 2.7 million records containing

```
 Post Code
 Longitude
 Latitude
```

I also have another `[Employee]` table with 200 rows and these columns:

```
 Employee Name
 Post Code
 Longitude
 Latitude
```

I need to know all the post codes from `[UK Post Code]` that are within a 30 mile radius to each employee

I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    e.name,
    e.postal_code AS employee_postcode,
    p.postcode AS covered_postcode,
    p.latitude AS covered_latitude,
    p.longitude AS covered_longitude
FROM
    Employee e
JOIN
    [UK Post Code] p ON 3959 * ACOS(
        COS(RADIANS(e.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(p.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,6), e.longitude) - CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,6), p.longitude))) +
        SIN(RADIANS(e.latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(p.latitude))
    ) <= 30
```

The end result I am expecting is

| Employee Name | Employee post code | Post code covered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | E6 1JS | E6 1JA |
| ABC | E6 1JS | E6 1JB |
| ABC | E6 1JS | E6 1JC |
| ABC | E6 1JS | E6 1JD |
| ABC | E6 1JS | E6 1JE |

etc...

I don't even mind just getting the outward code

| Employee Name | Employee outward code | outward code covered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | E6 | E6 |
| ABC | E6 | E7 |
| ABC | E6 | E8 |

The challenge I am facing is that the above code takes forever to run and just doesn't stop running.

I wanted to see if there's an optimal way to run this code.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've provided? You don't mention what it is that's happening, and what you expect to happen instead. See [ask]

Comment: Instead of using trig primitives, why not use T-SQL's built-in support for GIS datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.Your question is very scarce of information. I advise you to integrate further knowledge.

I can suggest this query for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    e.name,
    e.postal_code AS employee_postcode,
    p.postcode AS covered_postcode,
    p.latitude AS covered_latitude,
    p.longitude AS covered_longitude
FROM
    Employee e
JOIN
    "UK Post Code" p ON ST_Distance(
        ST_Point(e.longitude, e.latitude),
        ST_Point(p.longitude, p.latitude)
    ) <= 48280.3  -- 30 miles in meters (1 mile ≈ 1609.34 meters)
```

This query is written In PostGIS, the ST_Point function is used to generate a geometric point, while ST_Distance calculates the distance between two geometries.

PostGIS extends the capabilities of the PostgreSQL relational database by adding support storing, indexing and querying geographic data.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post. I only have access to SQL and I get this error 'ST_Point' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: [ST_Point](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) is a function in PostGis (ex. `SELECT ST_Point( -71.104, 42.315);`)